# Looping through XML nodes and reusing elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this

```
  <table>
  <header>
    <c0 type="string">name</c0>
    <c1 type="ip_address">last_ip_address</c1>
  </header>
  <body>
    <r>
      <c0>CHDB207</c0>
      <c1>172.18.151.57</c1>
  <c2>Locarno</c2>
   </r>
<r>
      <c0>CHDB100</c0>
      <c1>172.18.151.58</c1>
  <c2>Milan</c2>
   </r>
  </body>
```

I want to loop through all r elements and built a result like

- c0 chdb207 chdb207
- c1 chdb207 172.18.151.57
- c2 chfb207 Locarno
- c0 chdb100 chdb100
- c1 chdb100 172.18.151.58
- c2 chdb100 Milan

So for each loop c0 should be reused in the result set.

I have the following code in vb.net

```vb
Dim root2 As XmlElement = document.DocumentElement
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = document.SelectNodes("table/body/r/*")

For Each elem As XmlNode In nodeList
    MsgBox(elem.Name & " " & headerList(0).InnerXml & " " & elem.InnerXml)
Next
```

My Problem is how to break out of the loop when all c-elemts of a node are iterated so that headerList(0) can be written as a variable and not static.

At the moment my result looks like this:

- c0 chdb207 chdb207
- c1 chdb207 172.18.151.57
- c2 chfb207 Locarno
- c0 chdb207 chdb100
- c1 chdb207 172.18.151.58
- c2 chdb207 Milan

Alternatively I could use the above stetic if I could iterate through each node section.

The number of c-elemts is not fixed as well as the number of node blocks.

*Edit*
Ultimately I want to write the XML content into a database. The database is fix and contains 4 columns:

- key > contains the C value
- hostname > contains the c0 element value of each block
- datavalue > contains the c element value at its key position
- runkey > static value read from a variable

The result will look like this:
* c0 hostname hostname 200
* c1 hostname ip 200
* c2 hostname whatever 200

Any help appreciated!
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using LINQ.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim xml = 
            <table>
                <header>
                    <c0 type="string">name</c0>
                    <c1 type="ip_address">last_ip_address</c1>
                </header>
                <body>
                    <r>
                        <c0>CHDB207</c0>
                        <c1>172.18.151.57</c1>
                        <c2>Locarno</c2>
                    </r>
                    <r>
                        <c0>CHDB100</c0>
                        <c1>172.18.151.58</c1>
                        <c2>Milan</c2>
                    </r>
                </body>
            </table>

        Dim xmlString = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString())

        Dim nodes =
            From el In xmlString.<table>.<body>.<r>
            Select el

        For Each node In nodes
            Dim nodeDescendants =
                From nd In node.Descendants
                Select nd

            Dim header = nodeDescendants(0).Value
            For Each nd In nodeDescendants
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", nd.Name, header, nd.Value)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Tested in LINQPad and dotnetfiddler.net, result:

```
c0 CHDB207 CHDB207
c1 CHDB207 172.18.151.57
c2 CHDB207 Locarno
c0 CHDB100 CHDB100
c1 CHDB100 172.18.151.58
c2 CHDB100 Milan
```

Comment: Hi Han, thank you very much this does the trick! I'm new to Linq > Could you tell me how to write each result line to a variable so that I could parse this into a sql table instead of using console.writeline? Thx & BR Dan

Comment: @Dan Edit your question and write how you would like to store it in your tables. Provide the table's columns.

Comment: Updated the question as requested. Tried to read through some tutorials for Linq but haven't found a solution yet ...

Answer (score 0):

Try following using XML Linq :

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("body").FirstOrDefault() _
                .Elements("r").Select(Function(x) New With { _
                    .c0 = x.Element("c0").Value,
                    .c1 = x.Element("c1").Value,
                    .c2 = x.Element("c2").Value
                }).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```